# Does crouching decrease spread?

Tags: team-fortress-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does crouching improve accuracy with most ranged weapons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28195/does-crouching-improve-accuracy-with-most-ranged-weapons)

Does it reduce the spread in which any gun is fired? For example, in the case of the Heavy, does crouch firing with the minigun reduce spread?  Or does it have little to no effect on where the bullets go?

Comment: I would be willing to bet the answer is no, but I haven't checked to be sure.

Comment: Did not see this in Duplicates page.  Oh well.

Comment: @Retrosaur Spread and accuracy aren't *really* the same thing, but given they are similar you just needed to try one more keyword :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, crouching has no effect on bullet spread. It's only use is reducing your hitbox and to help jump on ledges.

Comment: And to spycrab :3

Comment: And to rocket jump.