# What does the server tag 'nodmgspread' mean in Team Fortress 2

Tags: team-fortress-2, terminology

When you search for TF2 games there are a variety of server tags, many of them simply announcing the name of the server.  One I see that I can't figure out is 'nodmgspread'

I assume that 'nodmgspread' means 'no damage spread', but what exactly does that mean?

Are they referring to the different amounts of damage that can occur at different ranges?
Does it refer to something else, or something like the spread of a shotgun blasts?

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3021/what-is-damage-spread-as-it-relates-to-team-fortress-2) and its answer explain what Damage Spread is, which is the range of damage that a weapon can deal (like, say, 90-110 damage). The answer also explains that some servers have it disabled for various reasons. I would guess that the tag you're referring to does just that, but I don't know for certain on account of never playing the game.

Comment: This one is about damage spread rather than damage falloff

Comment: When I said range, I meant "range of values" not "range of distance". Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: Lol, I realized that after I opened my big mouth.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several server options that affect weapon damage in Team Fortress 2, and they're often confused:

**Weapon Spread** -- With this turned on, hitscan weapons, such as shotguns, will have the same non-random pattern of "bullets" each time they are used. Default is ON.

**Damage Spread** -- Each weapon normally has a minimum and maximum damage. No Damage Spread means that each weapon will do a set, average, damage rather than varying between attacks. Default is ON. (Critical hits always do 3 times damage)

**Damage Falloff** -- Normally, the damage dealt by a weapon decreases the farther away you are for your target. If this is turned off, A rocket detonating right next to you and a rocket shot from the opposite side of the map will do equivalent damage. Crits are *never* affected by Damage Falloff. Default is ON.

The default is to have Damage Spread ON. Nodmgspread refers to servers which have turned it OFF.

Comment: I think that you should clarify which of these does `nodmgspread` refer to

Comment: The default is to have Damage Spread ON. Nodmgspread refers to servers which have turned it OFF.

Comment: The default is to have fixed weapon spread OFF (not ON).

Answer (score 4):

There's a forum post on this over at SteamPowered.com.

Normally damage done to someone is randomised from a range of values.

> No dmg spread gets rid of the random part, so you'll still do less damage the further away you are from the baddies, but there's no randomness thrown in.

[Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1567830)

Comment: To clarify -- the default TF2 Behavior is to have damage vary both within a base range AND with distance.